# Colombia Inter-City Bus Route and Time-Tables

Tags: buses, colombia

Is there a site where one can find bus routes between cities in Colombia and their time-tables where the information is reliable and up to date? Otherwise multiple web-sites, maybe per bus company? Only I don't know which they are and my searches so far have find highly dated or unreliable info from third-parties.

Specifically I am looking for bus schedules between cities on the Altantic coast, along the Cartagena, Barranquilla and Santa Marta corridor.

Comment: I think your best bet is to try and understand which are the main bus hubs of the region, and look for individual websites.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying. I found some long distance bus companies but with limited coverage and none reaches the coast so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like JoErNanO suggests, you should look at websites of the bus hubs, called "Terminals".  That being said, the info is probably out of date.  I'd suggest asking the locals and arriving super early.  Latin american transportation is not as punctual as what you'd expect from the first world.

[Terminal Cartagena](http://www.terminaldecartagena.com/informacion.html)

[Terminal Barranquilla](http://www.ttbaq.com.co/TT/)

Santa Marta doesn't seem to have a schedule.

Comment: This is the right answer. I just came back from there and there is no central  resource but each terminal has a list of buses companies which serves it and each of those has a website, many with accurate time tables.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com) to find local bus routes. http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Cartagena-Colombia/Barranquilla

Comment: The time tables there seem to have little connection to reality. Things are probably too rapidly changing as even my guidebook from 2015 was wrong. You have to go to the individual bus company sites to get reliable schedules.